# HOW: Ubuntu Linux in Bengali?

Tags: linux, localization, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-unity

**How to change my Ubuntu setup in Bengali language ?**
I want every menu, every text to be in Bengali.

Once I had a very old version of *Fedora* which had this feature, but I can't find it in *Ubuntu*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look in the `Language support` app (accessible from Unity).

Then select `Install / Remove Languages` Choose Bengali in the list.

And finally, put Bengali at the top of the list in `Language for menus and windows`.

And click on Apply System-Wide.

Along the process, some packages should be installed.

Comment: Just one more question -
How to make the font size bigger ?
Default Bengali font is too small.

Comment: @Ayan Don: Please have a look at [these](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool) [applications](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool).